# Query to get data depending upon a variable not present in database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I am using backpack laravel and I am trying to send a sms to those clients whose subscription will expire in next 7 days.

I have a column name `expiry_date` in my database but do not have a column for day_difference.

I am not able to find a solution for this problem like how should I form a query like:

```
DB::table('clients')->where('expiry_date', 'is greater than 7 days from today_date')->first();
```

Sorry It is just a rough patch and I want to make it fair.

This is what I have tried

```
public function notifyPending() {
    $today_date = Carbon::now();
    $entries = Clients::all()->where('gym_code',Auth::user()->gym_code);

    foreach ($entries as $k => $entry) {

        $data_differences[] = $today_date->diffInDays(Carbon::parse($entry->expiry_date), false);

        for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($data_differences);$i++) {

            if ($data_differences[$i] = 7) {

            }

        }
    }


}
```

I will call this function on a button by overriding listview of crudcontroller.

> so what I want is an array of mobile numbers which have there 7 days left in expiry of their subscription.

Comment: which database lang  you are using? mysql or other?

Comment: mysql it is sir

Comment: $diff=date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 days")); put it where expiry_date="$diff"

Comment: Sorry for the title @TimBrownlaw I will change it. I was too confused so I added this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can get the date after 7 days using PHP

```
$diff=date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 days"));
```

then you can use this **$diff** variable in your query

```
where('expiry_date', $diff)
```

Comment: I want to notify client 7 days before expiry_date. So it should be "-7 days" or "+7 days" Sir?

Comment: Here you will get the list of clients who will expire on 18-11-2017. No now you can message all to them who will expire on 18--11-2017 from today date 11-11-2017. so it should be +7

Comment: Okay let me try.

Comment: where('expiry_date', $diff) this is correct please update it sir. It is working!!